# Real-time Iteration over SVG objects

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg

For example i have this in html

```
<svg id="svg-img1" width="100%" height="100%" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <line x1="0" y1="0" x2="0" y2="0" style="stroke:black; stroke-width:1px;"></line>
    <line x1="0" y1="0" x2="0" y2="0" style="stroke:black; stroke-width:1px;"></line>
    <line x1="0" y1="0" x2="0" y2="0" style="stroke:black; stroke-width:1px;"></line>
    <line x1="0" y1="0" x2="0" y2="0" style="stroke:black; stroke-width:1px;">  </line>
</svg>
```

and this in my js

```
$('svg').find('line').each(function(){
    $(this).attr('style','stroke:red');
    sleep(10);
});
```

and "sleep" function

```
function sleep(ms) {
  ms += new Date().getTime();
  while (new Date() < ms){}
}
```

When executing, the color of my lines changes at once for everyone. And I need the color of the lines to change in turn, and so that it can be seen as one color after another changes color. Something similar to animation

Tried without jquery - the same result

Comment: why using that sleep function and not the build-in and pretty well working [`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout) or [`setInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval)?

Comment: Put your sleep function in a `setTimeout` function. It will do the trick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of sleep, you can use `window.setTimeout` to execute a function after a certain delay. So, you could do something like this:

```
$('svg').find('line').each(function(index, element){
    window.setTimeout(function() {
        $(element).attr('style','stroke:red');
    }, index * 100);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the SVG animate element:

> ```
>     <animate id="a14" attributeName="stroke" from="black" to="red" 
>  dur="3s" begin="9s;al4.end+3s" stroke="freeze" />
> ```

**NOTE:** Do not cut and paste the code above, it has been broken in the middle so that it can be seen without scrolling.

- `attributeName`: The name of the attribute to animate
- `from`: Starting value
- `to`: Ending value
- `dur`: Duration of animation
- `begin`: When to begin; this particular set of values says: start in 9 seconds; (referenced this animate element by id) to end in 3 seconds
- `stroke`: The attribute that's being animated, this attribute will stop after it has animated,

**SNIPPET**

```html
<svg id="svg-img1" width="100%" height="100%" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">

    <line x1="0" y1="10" x2="400" y2="10" style="stroke:black; stroke-width:1px;">
    <animate id="a11" attributeName="stroke" from="black" to="red" dur="3s" begin="0s;al1.end+3s" stroke="freeze" />
    </line>
    
    <line x1="0" y1="20" x2="400" y2="20" style="stroke:black; stroke-width:1px;">
    <animate id="a12" attributeName="stroke" from="=black" to="red" dur="3s"  begin="3s;al2.end+3s" stroke="freeze" />
    </line>
    
    <line x1="0" y1="30" x2="400" y2="30" style="stroke:black; stroke-width:1px;">
    <animate id="a13" attributeName="stroke" from="black" to="red" dur="3s" begin="6s;al3.end+3s" stroke="freeze" />
    </line>
    
    <line x1="0" y1="40" x2="400" y2="40" style="stroke:black; stroke-width:1px;">
      <animate id="a14" attributeName="stroke" from="black" to="red" dur="3s" begin="9s;al4.end+3s" stroke="freeze" />
     </line>
     
</svg>
```